# trouble in running for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have created a function for splitting values and run in a for loop but the for loop terminates after a single loop.

If I have an array with 4 items then it runs only one time:

```
function color_change() {
    //alert(document.getElementById("dom-target"));
    var div_fgh = document.getElementById("dom-target");
    var myData = div_fgh.textContent;
    //alert(myData);
    alert(myData);
    var stall_wished= myData;
    var array_WW= stall_wished.split(",");
    alert(array_WW.length);
    for (j=0;j<array_WW.length;j++){
        var wished_stalls = array_WW[j];
        alert(wished_stalls);
        document.getElementById(wished_stalls).style.background="#F90";
    }
```

}

Comment: what you are getting in alert(myData); ?

Comment: Use var j = 0, in your code, so that it is a local variable, and does not conflict with any other variable named j.

Comment: What `alert(myData)` says?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vipinwasim/vkgg9rg1/6/

Comment: please check this i am triying this way

Comment: see my edited answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

1. http://jsfiddle.net/40y8a3p3/

see the console you get an error in it.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

this is because there is no element defined with ids `1` , `2` , `3` , `4` , `5`

so for the first time it gets into loop gives you an alert then there is error and it breaks.

define all the ids, and it will work

here it is :http://jsfiddle.net/40y8a3p3/1/

2. And according to what `dsfq` pointed out in another answer, I have another option of solving it, if there is a space( characters which results into array of string that don't exactly match elements ids) inside the text you can see this http://jsfiddle.net/40y8a3p3/3/

> Edit: According to OP's comment below, I made some changes to the
>   code.. http://jsfiddle.net/vkgg9rg1/10/ I just need to trim the white
>   spaces before finding the element by ID , since it may contain white
>   spaces.

Comment: please check this i am trying this type
http://jsfiddle.net/vipinwasim/vkgg9rg1/6/

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in untidy result of string split operation. Very likely that there are spaces around `,` characters which results into array of string that *don't exactly match* elements ids. So as the result `document.getElementById(wished_stalls)` returns `null` and loop fails after the first round.

Use regexp in split method:

```
var array_WW = stall_wished.split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

Here is the demo where you can see the difference **http://jsfiddle.net/ngy28ky2/**

Comment: please check this i am trying this type
http://jsfiddle.net/vipinwasim/vkgg9rg1/6/

Comment: @user2897328 Because you need to check if the div with such id exists: http://jsfiddle.net/vkgg9rg1/8/

Comment: i checked your fiddle but there is one more problem in this function in for loop array have 3 or 4 values but its runs only one time how can i execute this according to array value or size

Answer (score 0):

```js
function color_change()
{
//alert(document.getElementById("dom-target"));
var div_fgh = document.getElementById("dom-target");
  var myData = div_fgh.textContent;
   // var myData = div_fgh.value;// use value if is input type.
console.log(myData);

var stall_wished= myData;
    var array_WW= stall_wished.split(",");
for (var j=0;j<array_WW.length;j++){

var wished_stalls = array_WW[j];

document.getElementById(wished_stalls).style.background="#F90";
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dom-target">1,2,3,4,5</div>
<div id="1" style="width:10px;height:10px;border: 2px solid;"></div>
<div id="2" style="width:10px;height:10px;border: 2px solid;"></div>
<div id="3" style="width:10px;height:10px;border: 2px solid;"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="color_change()" value="Click"/>
```

see if you are trying something like this:

Comment: please check this i am trying this type
http://jsfiddle.net/vipinwasim/vkgg9rg1/6/